# Bitshift Char Array

Tags: c, arrays, char, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

If I want to bit shift the integer `5` by 3, so `int a = 5;   int b = a << 3;`, the result would be `40` in decimal as `5` is `101` and `40` is `101000`.

What if however, I have the following `char` array:
`00000 00101` and by bit shifting three to the left, I want the result to be `00001 01000`. So I want to accommodate for the `0`'s padding. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant an actual `char` array, you can use `memmove()` and `memset()`:

```
char str[] = "0000000101";

int shift = 3;
int length = strlen(str);

memmove(str, str + shift,length - shift);
memset(str + length - shift,'0',shift);

//  Result:
//  "0000101000"
```

Comment: You're shifting right, rather than left, and overflowing the array, because you `memmove()` `length` bytes, not `length - shift`.

Comment: Thanks, I saw your first comment and fixed it a few min. ago. EDIT: I'm shifting left. I've tested it.

Comment: Yes you are, I mentally flipped the order of `src` and `dst` in memmove. Your current code is correct.

Comment: I think OP wanted to shift by three _bits_. Can't do that with memmove.

Comment: @DanielFischer: It's not entirely clear what the OP wants. The way I'm reading it, the bits are stored as a char array where each char is either `'0'` or `'1'`. So it's unclear until the OP clarifies it.

Comment: Yes, hence I _think_, not know.

Comment: Guys, Assume I have a char array of: `0000000101`. I want to shift it by, lets say, 3. So I want it: `0000101000`. If I set a variable as `5`, it will become `40` (as shown above).

Comment: How is `0000000101` represented? As a char array as in my answer? What's the data-type? Can you show us a before and after example in C code so we know exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Access the buffer with a 16-bit pointer, use htons to take care of endian issues

```
char c[2] = {0, 5};

uint16_t* p16 = (uint16_t*)c;

*p16 = htons((ntohs(*p16) << 3));
```